# Adding exceptions to mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I got my basic redirects work with the `mod_rewrite` module. When requesting pages e.g. `localhost/home` it's correctly redirecting to `localhost/index.php?page=home`, but I have a problem with exceptions.

I created a folder `api` where I store files by category e.g. `api/auth/register.php` and `api/customer/create.php`. I tried to make rewrite rule that contains 2 params (in this example *auth* and *customer*) so basically it just drops the `.php` off from the url.

The rule that I made is following

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)/(.*)/?$ api/$1/$2.php [L]
```

After adding that line to my .htaccess, problems started to occur. For example my `.css` and `.js` files started to redirect. So maybe I need to make some exeption for the apis? Have you some other ideas to improve my rewrite rules?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)/(.*)/?$ api/$1/$2.php [L] # problems started to occur after adding this line
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` will affect only the first following `RewriteRule` so you need the keep them next to your initial Rule, and move the added one above them (with its own conditions). 
Also, your `/api` rule is not strict enough (`(.*)` will pick anything, including the slashes), which might not matter in you case, but still. I sugest you try with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ api/$1/$2.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```